# Multiboot a cloned drive with windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, multi-boot, clone

I have cloned a windows installed drive from an old hard disk to an empty space(f:) of a new hard disk, the new hard disk already has a windows bootable c: drive.

The new hard disk now has,

1. a bootable c: drive,
2. a non bootable windows in f: drive

How do I make the f: drive as bootable ?

Things I have tried,

1. using easyBCD added an entry to point to f drive, 
   this method didn't work and ended in a error status:0xc0000001 with info:After multiple tries, the operating system on your PC failed to start, so it needs to be repaired.
2. using a windows installation USB disk, booted and tried the startup repair option for the entry created by bcd.
3. using command line in troubleshoot option while boot, deleted bcd and rebuild it, 2 installations successfully found and added but on booting the f: drive, error:0xc000021a appears

Comment: What versions of Windows are on the 2 discs?

Comment: Its possible the Windows installation on that drive is corrupt, will it boot with the new drive disconnected? If not leave the new drive disconnected and try a repair again.

Comment: Some repair guides here>>>>https://neosmart.net/wiki/0xc000021a/

Comment: I tried to check if the original hard disk drive (the one I cloned) boots properly, and it doesn't, so the problem was not due to cloning or repair methods, the original drive must be corrupted. Thanks @Moab for the help.